# What is the 'tiger' in 'The Long Song'?

Tags: meaning, the-long-song, andrea-levy

One of the fictional accounts of July's birth in *The Long Song* (historical novel, set in 1830s Jamaica, when slavery was coming to an end), describes a 'tiger', without the usual appearance belonging to that of a tiger:

> While a further version had a tiger, with its **long, spiky snout and six legs,** sniffing at the baby July, thinking her as food. *- Ch. 2*

The novel uses some Jamaican patois; however, I cannot find any alternative meanings of 'tiger'. What (mythical?) animal is this describing?

Comment: There *are* tigers in Jamaican folklore (e.g. the story of how Anansi took the stories from Tiger). I haven't read the context surrounding this quote, but [could it be](https://skemman.is/bitstream/1946/23600/2/Anna_Marie_Fennefoss_Nielsen_BA_THESIS_SECURED.pdf) that this "tiger with long spiky snout and six legs" is just a bit of nonsense and not meant to represent any actual (or even mythical) creature?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It certainly *could* be a bit of nonsense because of the context; the novel opens with several metafictional stories of how July was born and this is one of them. I'm just curious as to which it is - entirely made up or referring to a creature.

Answer (score 3):

While I can’t find any verification of this beast being colloquially named a ‘tiger’, it certainly fits its livery:

[image: Metamasius hemipterus-weevil with orange and black colouring and long snout]

This insect is [Metamasius hemipterus](https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/33576) (West Indian cane weevil), a pest of sugar cane fields. With tiger-like colouring, six legs and a long snout, it must be a strong candidate for this ‘tiger’.

The description that July gives of her birth is fantastical, she is small enough to slip unnoticed from the womb, to be blown away by the wind, to be held cupped in the palm of her mother’s hand, swaddled in a handkerchief. At that size such a beast would be as dangerous to her as a true tiger to a non-fantastically-scaled child.

Comment: That actually fits incredibly well! Especially with the other miniaturising descriptions, so I’m very happy with this interpretation. Thank you!